# Bugzilla: bugs are not showing up (show up in DB and everything seems to be fine)

Tags: bugzilla

I just installed Bugzilla locally and it seems that everything is fine. I can create new products and components. I can also file new bugs and they show up in the database.
But when I want to view them in the web interface, they won't show up.
Instead, at the top of the page this shows up:

```
Product: ARRAY(0x3735378    Component: ARRAY(0x4275650)    Resolution: ARRAY(0x42755a8)
```

and then below the "Zarro Boogs found."

I couldn't find any information on that on the web, did anybody have similar issues? Thank you!

Comment: Even I am facing same issue, Did you get it fixed? let me know if yes please.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the bugs table in techzilla database and verify if the bug details are getting updated.
The cgi file which corresponds to the listing of bugs is buglist.cgi.
Template file is:-global/message.html.tmpl

Answer (score 2):

"Zarro Boogs found." is showing because, the values are not correctly entering in the query to display the buglist.

It is evident from the display,
       Product: ARRAY(0x3735378    Component: ARRAY(0x4275650)    Resolution: ARRAY(0x42755a8)

it is because of the looping problem.
check the display code in the template file or buglist file and correct the loop, then it will dsiplay properly

Answer (score 2):

Jenifer,

Yes, It is because of the zero value in the query. We can check it, by printing the query and checking the value in DB.

Inserts a Named Query (a "Saved Search") into the database, or updates a Named Query that already exists..

Answer (score 0):

We had similar problem. Bugs were not showing in search result list. The problem was in the **name of the product** when the name of the product was with diacritics (e.g. Czech, Slovak, etc...). When the name of the product is in US ASCII it is all Ok.