# Bugzilla - Host upgraded perl - browse/search is the only function failing any way to update just that?

Tags: perl, bugzilla

The bugzilla install is very old now (4.0.1) and although it would be best, upgrading is a real pain as I suck at Perl related stuff. It has worked with no issue for many years and stopped in December. On checking the serverhost changed to Perl 5.16.3. Originally it was 5.8.8 and even after 15.10 it worked fine.

The issue I get is very similar to this issue - [Bugzilla: bugs are not showing up (show up in DB and everything seems to be fine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701792/bugzilla-bugs-are-not-showing-up-show-up-in-db-and-everything-seems-to-be-fine)
But it is not a template or character problem (the site ran fine with no changes) that I can see and happened the same week the host updated Perl , so I am 99% sure it is Perl related. I am assuming the issue is with either buglist.cgi itself or search pm. Any time I browse or search the Product, component, resolution etc shows "ARRAY and a number. e.g.      Product: ARRAY(0x30090f0) Component: ARRAY(0x3993420) Resolution: ARRAY(0x3993378).

The bugzilla is only accessible internally (but hosted by a third-party, so no admin) it only allows user accounts access to search and browse so I cannot demo the issue. Is there a known depreciated Perl command?

Would love to fix but may have to install a new version and import DB, last time it took a few weeks to get running hence looking to avoid that for now.

[image: Screenshot as requested]

Comment: You could technically install an older version of Perl in a directory of your choice, and change the shebang line to use that build of `perl`. (Note the correct spelling of the name of the language: Perl.)

Comment: Relying on the system Perl to run applications is discouraged for this reason. If you want to keep old software working, use [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/) to install and manage Perl and point Bugzilla at it.

Comment: Will that work on a bluehost hosted server? Either the install or perlbrew? I have a ticket with them now as well to see if we can get it changed back.

Comment: Re "*Will that work on a bluehost hosted server?*", Can you get a shell? Can you run `gcc`? If so, probably yes. /// Re "*Either the install or perlbrew?*", The latter is just a way of doing the former. /// Re "*I have a ticket with them now as well to see if we can get it changed back*", I can't speak for them, but I find this unlikely. (5.16 was released almost 9 years ago! My web host uses 5.26, which is 5 years newer)

Comment: I do have shell via putty that was how it was originally setup and the extra modules added. I can attempt that tomorrow. I am also making a copy so I can experiment. I had a similar issue with php (different domain) when it moved from 5 to 7 but i found some tools to check the code for compatibility. I only had to edit 2 line and be back on track was hoping for a similar result with this.

Comment: Can you add `use diagnostics` to the top of `buglist.cgi` and see if you get any interesting output?  That could tell you the exact line causing the problem.  More importantly, cant you update Bugzilla?

Comment: If it works on 5.10 and fails on 5.16.3, then the cause of the problem will be one of the changes listed in [perl5120delta](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perl5120delta.pod), [perl5140delta](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perl5140delta.pod) or [perl5160delta](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perl5160delta.pod).

Comment: Which version of Bugzilla is it? Perhaps there is a newer version that is compatible with newer versions of Perl.

Comment: Is anything useful written to the web server error log?

Comment: cpanel - suexec error log messages -  buglist.cgi and describecomponents.cgi. I added use diagnostic to both, also -wT is already set. The page offers no diagnostic feedback. It must be OK with the result, so sees no error, I think query gets formatted wrong so the result says Zero bugs found but that is because the query is not being processed correctly. I may end up having to update (yes there are newer versions), but all I can remember is how painful initial install was taking several weeks and a ton of google, 10 years on there might be way more help topics so maybe it is easier now.

Comment: When migrating PHP, this site saved me a ton of work. Found the 1 syntax I needed to update after going from 5 to 7 - https://phpcodechecker.com/ I have been trying to find similar for perl with no success.

The host confirms they moved to a new machine and not all the things I had before are available so they recommend, of course, upgrading. I have a parallel install, upgrading from such an old version could be a challenge. I already found the compiler is missing so another ticket :( I will let you know but it seems as **I couldn't track down a simple fix I must upgrade.**

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the page?  The `ARRAY` text is coming from the script trying to print an array reference as if it were a string.

Comment: I added  a screen shot to main post. I am almost done building the new version, what a headache, compiler was missing, modules are newer than bugzilla wants and it had issues the use reference was higher then the version it wanted so had to edit perl modules in perl folder, several other problems probably burned about 8 to 10 hrs so far. Got voted down? Why, issue I was hoping to solve quick and easy not spend days on new installs, if it can't be done just say that.

Comment: To clarify for comment 1 by ikegami 2 installing another Perl is not possible I have no permission for that I have to use what is provided. So it was fix code or move on.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue. After digging a little figured this is an issue with the Perl version. In Search.pm, `$params->param("field$chart-$row-$col", shift(@$ref));` this line is causing the issue. With 5.8.8 its returning Array object, whereas with 5.16.3 it is returning SCALAR.

My option is to install 5.8.8 and re-install the compatible modules. Or, is there any quick workaround for this?

Update:

Going through the docs, figured that 4.0.10 version of bugzilla has added support for Perl 5.16. Copied the CGI.pm from that and tested.. bugzilla is working. This is a bad hack. But, at least now I know that upgrading to 4.0.10 is another viable solution instead of upgrading Perl.

Comment: I knew I could not be alone in this but hard to get any info. I was able to do an update I cloned the full structure used tar, had a few module issue when it has a newer module than required but the USE line in that module specifies a lower version that bugzilla wants it throws an error so editing the use version to match (which is still lower than the actual so works OK) seems to resolve this. I am going to swap but before I do I want to try this work around as I figured it might be something like this.